# How to save custom tableview cells separately in an array

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewdidload

Okay so I'm probably really noobie at programming but I've been working on this problem for a while and can't figure it out. I have an **expandable** `tableView` that dynamically **"Add"** and **"Delete"** rows.

Two issues:
1) The only way I can load the `textFields` and `labels` in my cell is to expand the `tableView` and click the load button. My code to save the `textFields` and `labels` is in `expandingcell.m` not in `viewController.m`. I want my info to load upon start up.

2) If I save on cells information, it saves the info I have in every single cell so when i load it, every single cell will load the same thing when I click the load button. 
any help would be so very greatly appreciated I've spend countless hours on this

```
  #import "ExpandingCell.h"

@implementation ExpandingCell
@synthesize DateLabel, CourseLabel, Date, Course, Score, Par, Putts, GIR;

- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender
{
    NSString *saveString = Date.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:saveString forKey:@"saveString"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    NSString *saveString1 = Course.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults1 setObject:saveString1 forKey:@"saveString1"];
    [defaults1 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString2 = Score.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults2 setObject:saveString2 forKey:@"saveString2"];
    [defaults2 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString3 = Par.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults3 setObject:saveString3 forKey:@"saveString3"];
    [defaults3 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString4 = Putts.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults4 setObject:saveString4 forKey:@"saveString4"];
    [defaults4 synchronize];

    NSString *saveString5 = GIR.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults5 setObject:saveString5 forKey:@"saveString5"];
    [defaults5 synchronize];

}

- (IBAction)Load:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString = [defaults objectForKey:@"saveString"];
    [Date setText:loadString];
    [DateLabel setText:loadString];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString1 = [defaults1 objectForKey:@"saveString1"];
    [Course setText:loadString1];
    [CourseLabel setText:loadString1];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString2 = [defaults2 objectForKey:@"saveString2"];
    [Score setText:loadString2];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults3 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString3 = [defaults3 objectForKey:@"saveString3"];
    [Par setText:loadString3];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults4 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString4 = [defaults4 objectForKey:@"saveString4"];
    [Putts setText:loadString4];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults5 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadString5 = [defaults5 objectForKey:@"saveString5"];
    [GIR setText:loadString5];
}
```

This next part may not be as important I don't know but I figured I would just paste all of it so you get the idea of what my program does

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
#import "ExpandingCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
- (IBAction)ADD:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[self tableView] reloadData];



    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    [_Fade setAlpha:0];

    _tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;

    _tableView.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7];
    _tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];


    //set index to -1 to say no cell is expanded or should expand
    selectedIndex = -1;

    titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //adds first row for the user

    NSUserDefaults *theDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    titleArray = [theDefault objectForKey:@"titleArray"] ;
    [theDefault synchronize];

}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return titleArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"expandingCell";

    ExpandingCell *cell = (ExpandingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExpandingCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }

    return cell;

}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        return 180;
    }
    else
    {
        return 40;
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        selectedIndex = -1;
        [UIView transitionWithView:tableView
                          duration:0.5f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^(void) {
                            [tableView reloadData];
                        } completion:NULL];
        return;
    }

    //just in case selected index changes for whatever reason
    if (selectedIndex != -1)
    {
        NSIndexPath *prevPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:prevPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [UIView transitionWithView:tableView
                      duration:0.5f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    animations:^(void) {
                        [tableView reloadData];
                    } completion:NULL];
}

- (BOOL) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)ADD:(id)sender
{
    [titleArray addObject:@"ExpandingCell"];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [titleArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}

- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (IBAction)SaveTable:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *theDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [theDefault setObject:titleArray forKey:@"titleArray"];
    [theDefault synchronize];

    [_Fade setAlpha:100];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [_Fade setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Please first of all reconsider all name of your methods.

Comment: most of the methods are defined, I'll rename others for clarity though. but my problem is still unresolved :(